# Sound Design course - London School Of Sound

Tags: design, course, london, masters-degree

Hi Everybody, i'm an Italian guy who will graduate at the conservaotry of Padova in this december as sound engineer. 
Recently i discovered (and start to love) the figure of Sound Designer into film and most important Videogame.
I know that now is late for the various MC, but i've seen this course of Sound Design at the London School Of Sound that starts in february and i wanna ask if somebody could give me a feedback about it. Is it a good course? Maybe there's other courses that start at the beginning of 2013?

Here the link of the course: http://www.londonschoolofsound.co.uk/mp181.php

Answer (score 1):

Hello Marco,

I didn't attend to this school, but after quick look at program course I must say - it looks like it's not what you're looking for. It is mainly focused on synthesis techniques and it feels that this course is rather prepaired for electronic musician/producer than a sound designer for film - there aren't any topics which are covering sound effects editing/designing for film and narrative concepts of film sound. Sound synthesis is widely used tool in sound design for film, but it's only a tool...

Comment: Agreed, I'm sure there would be some skills you could take from it but the course is definitely music rather than post.

Comment: More like just synthesizers 101.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Marco,

I did the Pro Tools 101 and 110 courses at London School of Sound. The classes are very small (there was only 2 of us) so you get a lot of attention, and the tutor was very good.

However, these courses are mainly aimed at people who want to learn how to use Pro Tools and plugins, not so much for techniques in sound design.

If you are already graduating as a Sound Engineer I'd recommend you look for a junior/entry level job in the industry and work you way up. There are plenty of Runner jobs at Post Production facilities around London.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could try NFTS, National Film and Theatre School, although they expect you to have some years of experience behind you before applying. So as above, get yourself into a studio, and do some freelance work and work a portfolio up.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else here said already, the course is mainly focusing on synth synthesis and not so much on on actual sound design.